# Trying to implement infinite scroll in Swift UItableView using willDisplayCell. Want to control the increment to be done once

Tags: ios, swift

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (indexPath.row == self.dataArray.count-30) {
        pageNumber += 1
        self.downloadTask()
    }
}
```

self.downloadTask() will use the pageNumber and download appropriate data.

Now soon after 30 or more rows are remaining to display, the page number is incrementing many times and I want to restrict it for only once till the self.downloadTask() is finished executing and later on come back and when another 30 rows are remaining to display in the UITableView.

How can I proceed in such a way that the pageNumber increments by 1 only once per having 30 rows remaining to display in the UITableView.

Comment: Please elaborate on what your goal is. It's also unclear from your initial question what pageNumber is, what downloadTask() does, and what threading you are using.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suspect that changing 30 to 3 will only reduce the frequency of the problem without actually solving it.  It is also likely that scrolling will seem choppy or irresponsive between page loads and/or when the use swipes very fast.

I would suggest using an absolute (rather than relative) calculation to determine when new data needs to be downloaded.

For example, if your downloadTask() function fetches 30 items at a time, you could process your dataArray in 30 item chunks and get the next chunk (page) as soon as any item in the last chunk is being displayed:

```
let wantPage = indexPath.row / 30 + 1
if wantPage > pageNumber
{
   pageNumber = wantPage
   downloadTask()
}
```

If downloadTask() gets fewer than 30 items at a time and you want the data to be 30 items ahead of the collection view's scroll position, you can simply add that number to the chunk (page) calculation:

```
let itemsPerPage = 10 
let wantPage     = (indexPath.row + 30) / itemsPerPage
if wantPage > pageNumber
{
   pageNumber = wantPage
   downloadTask()
}
```

Your pageNumber variable will eventually reach a point where no more data is available (i.e. less than the items per page) and this "absolute" calculation will automatically stop calling the downloadTask().

Answer (score -1):

I changed the array count check to be 3 and was able to implement it.
Updated code looks as follows:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
if (indexPath.row == self.dataArray.count-3) {
    pageNumber += 1
    self.downloadTask()
}
```

}